# How can i read multiple http requests?

Tags: java, http

I'm making a program that reads video files from a server and it reproduces them. I'm reading the files by segments(of seconds) and for that i need to make multiple http requests my problem is that once i make the new request the inputstream still  has data from the previous request.

Example

```
    String server = "localhost";
    int port = 8080;

    socket = new Socket(server, port);
    os.write(("GET /Lifted-" + "160" + "p.dat HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    InputStream rcv = socket.getInputStream();
.................................................................

socket = new Socket(server, port);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
InputStream rcv = socket.getInputStream();
os.write(("GET /Lifted-" + currentRes + "p.dat HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n").getBytes());
            os.write(("Range: bytes="+Integer.toString(offset)+"-"+Integer.toString((int) (offset+aux))).getBytes());
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(rcv);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this yourself by hand rather than using `java.net.URL` or another HTTP client to do the awkward bits for you?

Comment: it's for a homework...